# Reconstruction of PIE consonants

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, germanic-languages

So, I have a question about the reconstruction of PIE consonants.

According to the Etymological Dictionaries, the words "rape" and "raven" have the same PIE root *ker- however how did "k" change into "r"? How did that come to be? I'd love to know if somebody could explain. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The idea is that the zero-grade of IE *ker, *kor, *kr gives Germanic hraben, with subsequent loss of the initial h-.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

To add on to fdb's answer:

The change of initial PIE **k* (and **ḱ*) to Proto-Germanic **h* is well-known (part of Grimm's Law), so that part of the derivation is completely expected and regular.

"Rape" might instead descend from Latin *rapiō*, in which case a different PIE root **h₁rep-* "take away, snatch" has been proposed (compare Greek ἐρέπτομαι); Latin didn't have the same change of initial **k* to **h* (compare *corvus* > corvid).

Comment: I thought he was thinking of "rape(seed)", which is believed to be from the same Germanic origin as "raven".

Comment: @fdb Ohh, that would make significantly more sense.